# Kubuntu File Upload Window Does Not Show Remote/Network Locations

Tags: kubuntu, files, kde, browser, upload

How do I get the File Upload window to display like the regular Dolphin one? The File Upload window does not show the remote/network locations. They do not even show up in Other Locations. That just shows Computer.

Note: I edited the Dolphin picture so my network shares are not shown.

[Dolphin Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFHxP.png)

[File Upload Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO2mw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix for Firefox. Thanks to Rick on Kubuntu Support on Telegram.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get install xdg-desktop-portal
sudo apt-get install xdg-desktop-portal-kde

Also, thanks to Zren for posting how to enter the command:
https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/a5cxwk/firefox_v64_can_now_use_the_kde_file_selection/

Right click the Firefox launcher in the app launcher > Edit Application
Application tab > Command GTK_USE_PORTAL=1 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox %u